# Type Error evaluating cells.not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm getting the following error on a jquery mobile app. Any ideas what this may be referring to and how to fix it?

```
10970TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$cells.not')
```

The error occurs infrequently. It seems to be related to the creation of hide/show toggles on table headers.

Comment: @timms I definitely will, if I knew which part of the entire app is helpful to share. Perhaps I phrased the question incorrectly?

Comment: With something like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/javascript) you could possibly debug it.

Comment: okay, seems like dynamically loaded content is sometimes rendered after page initialization. Adding `$('#page1').page();` to an initialization function appears to have solved the problem.

Comment: Goodie :) You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted after the 2 day limit so the question will be set as solved.